# Choosing which attributes to return with WFS?

Tags: wfs, cql

I am trying to use this documentation:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature

to figure out a way where I can limit the attributes returned by a wfs call. If we use this example, I am expecting that this call would only return the `GEOMETRY` and the `LOCALITY` attribute

```
https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/wfs?
SERVICE=WFS&
VERSION=2.0.0&
REQUEST=GetFeature&
outputFormat=application%2Fjson&
typeNames=WHSE_IMAGERY_AND_BASE_MAPS.GSR_AIRPORTS_SVW&
SRSNAME=EPSG%3A3005&
propertyName=LOCALITY&
COUNT=10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check also the schema with DescribeFeatureType.

https://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/pub/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&typenames=WHSE_IMAGERY_AND_BASE_MAPS.GSR_AIRPORTS_SVW

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:pub="http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/geo/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="WHSE_IMAGERY_AND_BASE_MAPS.GSR_AIRPORTS_SVWType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="CUSTODIAN_ORG_DESCRIPTION" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="BUSINESS_CATEGORY_CLASS" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="BUSINESS_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="OCCUPANT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="SOURCE_DATA_ID" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="SUPPLIED_SOURCE_ID_IND" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="AIRPORT_NAME" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DESCRIPTION" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PHYSICAL_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ALIAS_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="STREET_ADDRESS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="POSTAL_CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="LOCALITY" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CONTACT_PHONE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CONTACT_EMAIL" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CONTACT_FAX" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="WEBSITE_URL" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IMAGE_URL" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="LATITUDE" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="LONGITUDE" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KEYWORDS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DATE_UPDATED" nillable="true" type="xsd:date"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SITE_GEOCODED_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AERODROME_STATUS" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AIRCRAFT_ACCESS_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DATA_SOURCE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DATA_SOURCE_YEAR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ELEVATION" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FUEL_AVAILABILITY_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="HELICOPTER_ACCESS_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="IATA_CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ICAO_CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="MAX_RUNWAY_LENGTH" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="NUMBER_OF_RUNWAYS" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OIL_AVAILABILITY_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="RUNWAY_SURFACE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SEAPLANE_ACCESS_IND" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TC_LID_CODE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SHAPE" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="SEQUENCE_ID" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA" nillable="true" type="xsd:hexBinary"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="WHSE_IMAGERY_AND_BASE_MAPS.GSR_AIRPORTS_SVW" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" type="pub:WHSE_IMAGERY_AND_BASE_MAPS.GSR_AIRPORTS_SVWType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

WFS server must send all the attributes which are not nillable in addition to what user requests with the PropertyName list. Therefory you get for example SOURCE_DATA_ID but you do not get AERODROME_STATUS and other nillable attributes.

Geometry is nillable and you do not ask for it and therefore it is not included in the result.

```
"SHAPE" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType"
```

Comment: +1 was just about to post this.  Can also check `minOccurs`, if `minOccurs="1"` then the attribute gets returned.

Comment: Interesting. So the implication are the some attributes are "sticky" and can't be dropped. What would the rationale be behind that?

Comment: The rational is that the schema says they are not optional and so they must be included as your returned feature is required to be of that schema